# Custom focus ring for NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion

I'm am able to draw a custom focus ring by subclassing the scrollView. My question is, how do I test if the textVeiw (that is inside the scrollView) has focus, in order to change the focus ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass the text view and override becomeFirstResponder.  That method will be called when the text view becomes the first responder, by clicking on it or tabbing from another responder.